# Extract data from html using python,

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have below sample HTML blocks. From each of these blocks I want to extract "alt" & "Author" using PYTHON & Beautifulsoup. I have parsed the html using beautiful soup. Can anyone help with script

```
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
            <h5 class="text-white alt-font font-weight-400 letter-spacing-1 margin-10px-bottom">INSPIRATIONAL QUOTES</h5>
            <span class="text-white-2 opacity8 alt-font mb-0 padding-20px-bottom">Find the perfect quote... and Pass It On®</span>

            <form class="search-box2 margin-30px-bottom" action="/inspirational-quotes" method="get">
                <div class="input-group add-on width-75 mx-auto sm-width-100">
                    <input name="q" type="text" value='' placeholder="Search our collection of inspiring quotes..." class="form-control" />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="ti-search text-small m-0"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row' id='all_quotes'>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 text-center margin-30px-bottom sm-margin-30px-top">

    <a href="/inspirational-quotes/7848-i-say-to-myself-that-i-shall-try-to-make-my"><img alt="I say to myself that I shall try to make my life like an open fireplace, so that people may be warmed and cheered by it and so go out themselves to warm and cheer. #&lt;Author:0x00007fde720f6b28&gt;" class="margin-10px-bottom shadow" src="https://assets.passiton.com/quotes/quote_artwork/7848/medium/20191231_tuesday_quote.jpg?1577388768" width="310" height="310" /></a>
    <h5 class='value_on_red'><a href="/inspirational-quotes/7848-i-say-to-myself-that-i-shall-try-to-make-my">CHEER</a></h5>
```

```
    <a href="/inspirational-quotes/7849-the-unselfish-effort-to-bring-cheer-to-others"><img alt="The unselfish effort to bring cheer to others will be the beginning of a happier life for ourselves. #&lt;Author:0x00007fde721154d8&gt;" class="margin-10px-bottom shadow" src="https://assets.passiton.com/quotes/quote_artwork/7849/medium/20191230_monday_quote.jpg?1577388731" width="310" height="310" /></a>
    <h5 class='value_on_red'><a href="/inspirational-quotes/7849-the-unselfish-effort-to-bring-cheer-to-others">CHEER</a></h5>
```

```
    <a href="/inspirational-quotes/8027-there-is-no-mistaking-love-it-is-the-common"><img alt="There is no mistaking love. It is the common fiber of life, the flame that heats our soul, energizes our spirit and supplies passion to our lives. #&lt;Author:0x00007fde7213df28&gt;" class="margin-10px-bottom shadow" src="https://assets.passiton.com/quotes/quote_artwork/8027/medium/20191226_thursday_quote.jpg?1576706550" width="310" height="310" /></a>
    <h5 class='value_on_red'><a href="/inspirational-quotes/8027-there-is-no-mistaking-love-it-is-the-common">LOVE</a></h5>
```

Comment: Please include the exact HTML blocks in question instead of the links

Comment: Devesh - I have copied source code, let me know if it helps

Comment: where is your python coding attempt at this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: The python code searches for `img` blocks in your html file. The script would also works with multiple `img` blocks in your html text. The `Author` block if found by splitting the string in two parts (I used the `#` symbol as seperator). I hope this helps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://values.com/inspirational-quotes" 
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser') 
table = soup.findAll('img') 

for image in table: 
    alt_table = image.attrs['alt'].split('#') 
    # Check with if-clause to prevent IndexError if no Author is found
    if len(alt_table) > 1:
        alt = alt_table[0] 
        author = alt_table[1]
        print('Alt: \'{}\'\nAuthor: \'{}\'\n'.format(alt,author))
    else:
        alt = alt_table[0]
        print("Only found alt. Alt: \'{}\'\n".format(alt))
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks sp4c. it is working but partly.I am getting values for alt = alt_author_list[0] but when I run author = alt_author_list[1] it gives of error"index out of range".

Comment: Okay, weird works for me. What do you get for `alt` and for `alt_author_list`?

Comment: `URL = "http://www.values.com/inspirational-quotes"`
`r = requests.get(URL)`
`soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')`
`table = soup.findAll('img')`
`for image in table:`
    `alt_table = image.attrs['alt'].split('#&lt')`
    `alt = alt_table[0]`
    `author = alt_table[1]`
    `print('Alt: \'{}\'\nAuthor: \'{}\'\n'.format(alt,author))`

Comment: Ok, actually I get `IndexError: list index out of range` now when I run your code .

Comment: but for author if you run author = alt_table[0], you will get values.. seems it is not splitting string properly and treats it as only 1 item list only, hence the out of range error.. let me know if you are able to fix it

Comment: If I do `image.attrs["alt"].split("#")` it works. `image.attrs["alt"].split("#&lt")` doesn't work. `&lt` in html stands for the less-than sign ("<") and &gt for the greater-than sign (">"). If I download the page with requests and print the page `&lt` and `&gt` are still `&lt` and `&gt`. But in some step BeautifulSoup decides to decode `&lt` and `&gt` to "<" and ">". That's why I than get `#<Author:0x00007fde70ef2b20>` for the Author tag and because of that the `....split("#&lt")` doesn't work for me. If it works for you than just do it like you did .

Comment: but problem is even if I use '#' i get values for alt = alt_table[0], but for author = alt_table[1]. it is returning  IndexError: list index out of range. problem persist in either case as am not getting values for 'author'

Comment: Sorry, I thought the code you sent worked for you. I took the html text you put in your question. When you download directly from the page the logo is also interpreted as an image, but it doesn't have any author. That's why the code fails. I'll updated my answer in a few minutes, to solve that problem.